# DOJO getting id of a widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using `dojo.parse` in order to initialize some widgets from html.

I need to get the ID for the widget being initialed a passed to another function.
using `var test = _WidgetBase.id;` I cannot get the id.

Any idea how to solve it?

```
   define([
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dijit/_WidgetBase',
        'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
        'dijit/_AttachMixin',
        'dojo/text!./templates/Button.html',
        'dojo/dom-style',
        'dojo/_base/fx',
        'dojo/_base/lang',
        'dojo/on',
        'dojo/mouse',
        'require',
        'ntv/WebpartInitializer',
    ], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _AttachMixin, template, domStyle, fx, lang, on, mouse, require, WebpartInitializer) {
        // automatically generated properties from state
        var test = _WidgetBase.id; // PROBLEM HERE
        var webpartInitializer = new WebpartInitializer(test);
        var autoProperties = webpartInitializer.getProperties(),
        // custom properties
        customs = {
            templateString: template,
            ntvType: 'Button',
            baseClass: "button",
            postCreate: function () {
                var domNode = this.domNode;
            },
            _setTitleAttr: function () {
                console.log('++++++ test');
            }
        };
        // create new class mixin
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _AttachMixin], lang.mixin(customs, autoProperties));
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your widget isn't initialized yet, there is no ID assigned yet. The ID will be available in the widget lifecycle after postMixInProperties has been run:

```
require([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/_WidgetBase',
], function (declare, _WidgetBase) {

    declare("CustomWidget", [
        _WidgetBase
    ], {
        preamble: function () {
            console.log('preamble: ' + this.id);
        },
        constructor: function () {
            console.log('constructor: ' + this.id);
        },
        postMixInProperties: function () {
            console.log('postMixInProperties: ' + this.id);
        },
        buildRendering: function () {
            console.log('buildRendering: ' + this.id);
        },
        postCreate: function () {
            console.log('postCreate: ' + this.id);
        },
        startup: function () {
            console.log('startup: ' + this.id);
        }
    });

    var customWidget = new CustomWidget();
    customWidget.startup();

});
```

Gives the follow results:

```
preamble:
constructor:
postMixInProperties: 
buildRendering: CustomWidget_0
postCreate: CustomWidget_0
startup: CustomWidget_0
```

So if you need to do something with that ID you must do it in buildRendering, postCreate or startup.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am using a similar solution right now, and using preamble so before postMixInProperties. Could you suggest preamble approch?

Comment: sorry, forgot about preamble in the lifecycle, it still goes undocumented in [http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#dijit-widgetbase](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#dijit-widgetbase). I'll edit that in. But it won't help you in this case, since it runs before constructor, the ID will not be available.

Comment: You could try to generate your own in preamble, maybe this answer is usefull to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182103/how-do-i-create-unique-ids-in-a-dojo-widget-template